# Верны ли мои следующие предположения по поводу настройки nginx и мест размещения разных файлов flask-проекта?

Tags: nginx, flask, vps, развертывание

Настраиваю nginx + gunicorn.

у меня есть папка с flask-проектом.
Но, **при деплое на vps**, наверное нужно добавлять туда не все папки и файлы,
а **исключить**: папку миграций и папку с виртуальным окружением.
а **добавить**: app.py, templates, static и базу данных

Что обозначает в главном конфигурационном файле эта строчка **include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;** ?

Здесь у меня лежит **главный конфиг /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**
а здесь я **хочу чтоб** он у меня лежал **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/configur.conf**

Чтоб указать, где расположен корень сайта, нужно прописать в **configur.conf** в контексте server:  **root /etc/nginx/sites-enabled;** ?

Comment: `include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;` - включение конфигов из всех *.conf файлов каталога, там  находятся динамически подгружаемые модули (mod-http-image-filter и другие). `а здесь я хочу чтоб он у меня лежал` - поправьте главный конфиг, добавив в http секцию инклюд: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/configur.conf`, или более правильно - `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` - эта строчка вообще идет изначально в nginx.conf. Либо запускайте nginx с опцией, которая явно указывает положение конфига.

Comment: `в контексте server` - да, или ниже, на уровне http и даже location. Но путь неверный. /etc/nginx/sites-enabled - это каталог nginx, а нужно указать путь к каталогу проекта, `/var/www/site.ru/public` например